# ASP.NET ListView Search & Edit not working

Tags: asp.net

I've got a ASP.NET ListView with search function. After retrieving a search result when I click on Edit button, the ListView Reresh and brings back the full list with edit mode selected on wrong record.

> e.g. Lets say I've 100 records on list
>   view. After search I've 2 records
>   displayed. When I click Edit button it
>   retrieves 100 records with wrong Edit
>   Row selected.

Could some please suggest what I should do to fix this bug.

Here's the code for search:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DS.SelectCommand = 
      "SELECT ReportName, ReportType, 
       FROM Table 
       WHERE ReportName LIKE @param 
       ORDER BY ReportType Desc";
   DS.SelectParameters.Add("Param", searchTxtBox.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
   DS.DataBind();
   ListView1.DataBind();               
}
```

Comment: It's ASP.Net OutofBox ListView

Comment: Provide the code of the Page_Load, EditButton_Click, Search function ..

Comment: Hi @Akram, i've updated my original post with code for search

Comment: Still need more code ...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are confusing the row-index of the record with the record-ID of the row.

Without any code to go on, it's really impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

Used the itemEditing event to pass the existing parameter (if exists) and use TSQL.